# How to stop DataGrid from flickering when using ObservableCollection?

Tags: wpf, observablecollection

I've been battling with `WPF` and the `ObservableCollection` for quite some time and now I need some help.

**This is the setup and requirements**

- Using MongoDB as the backing database
- Storing huge amounts of log data in the database
- The UI must be able to display the logs as they are inserted into the database (real time-ish)
- The UI DataGrid is bound to an `ObservableCollection`
- The UI DataGrid is and must be paged due to memory usage and having millions of records
- When viewing the log, if a new entry is created and displayed, one must be removed as well; this is just because of paging and having a set page size (50 log entries will only ever be shown at one time)
- Using ActiveMQ to signal when a new log entry has been created

So essentially this is a rolling log view where one entry comes in and one entry goes out. I must maintain the selected item and show updates in real time (which is why I'm using the `ObservableCollection`). The log can be filtered and pages can be navigated so I figured it would be easiest to fetch the entire page when there are new log entries and display it; this would also allow me to get entries that might have been missed previously.

I've had so many issues with this, including problems with updating the collection on a background thread and the most recent is `DataGrid` "flickering" when a new entry is created. I'm assuming the flickering is caused by refreshing the whole collection every time but the alternative (adding and removing items manually) is much more complex and I'd prefer not to go that route due to the complexities of the filtering and paging.

Are there any good patterns or suggestions for stopping this "flickering" or maybe a better way to implement a filterable log view that updates in real time?

**Xaml**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Entries, IsAsync=True}"
      AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True"
      CanUserSortColumns="False"
      EnableColumnVirtualization="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True"
      VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Timestamp" Binding="{Binding Timestamp}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="From" Binding="{Binding MessageFrom}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="To" Binding="{Binding MessageTo}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding MessageType}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

ViewModel code for binding that I've used

```
//option 1
public ViewModel() { this.Entries = new ObservableCollection<Model>(); }

public void UpdateData()
{
    this.Entries.Clear();
    foreach (Model m in FetchModels())
        this.Entries.Add(m);
}

public ObversableCollection<Model> Entries { get; private set; }

//option 2
private List<Model> m_Entries = new List<Model>();

public void UpdateData()
{
    this.m_Entries.Clear();
    this.m_Entries.AddRange(FetchModels());
    this.NotifyPropertyChanged(() => this.Entries);
}

public ObversableCollection<Model> Entries { get { return new ObservableCollection<Model>(this.m_Entries); } }

//option 3
public ViewModel() { this.Entries = new ObservableCollection<Model>(); }

public void UpdateData()
{
    var tmp = this.Entries;
    this.Entries = null;

    tmp.Clear();
    foreach (Model m in FetchModels())
        tmp.Add(m);

    this.Entries = tmp;
    this.NotifyPropertyChanged(() => this.Entries);
}

public ObversableCollection<Model> Entries { get; private set; }
```

As soon as I remember more things I've tried, I'll post it.

Comment: BTW, 1 - paging or any other rather hacky techniques are probably not necessary in WPF due to built-in UI virtualization. 2 - if you rebind the entire collection there's going to be a performance penalty no matter what, manipulate indiviual items instead.

Comment: @HighCore That's not true. If I grab all 6 million records from the database without using a query to limit the amount returned to 50 records then the client's memory is used up pretty fast. Even if WPF has virtualization, it still has a list of 6 million records in memory; it's just not displaying it all at the same time.

Comment: yes, however that doesn't have anything to do with the UI... if you grab 6m records from a DB in a console application you will have just the same problem. My advice still stands you should manipulate individual items rather than rebinding the entire collection all the time.

Comment: @HighCore BTW, I didn't post code initially because the project is a sensitive project and I am unable to post code. The code I did post to appease the down-voting God's is not actual code in the project but as close as I can get it without getting in trouble.

Comment: all your options do the same. I insist, do item-by-item operations rather than re-doing the collection everytime. I'm sure your items must have some kind of Id? use LINQ and also, do your `FetchModels()` stuff asynchronously using `async await`.

Comment: @HighCore I agree that manipulating individual records would be ideal but because of filtering and paging and the way MongoDB doesn't have timestamp granularity down to the millisecond (only the second), I need to sort by my own timestamp which prevents me from easily determining which entry to add or remove.

Comment: @HighCore yes, they have an Id and UpdateData is happening on a separate thread. So how would you suggest that I add missing records, remove records no longer needed all while maintaining the correct sorting order?

Comment: For one, you should be sorting/filtering using a `CollectionView` instead of manually sorting/filtering if doing so breaks your business logic or complicates matters.

Comment: I need to sort on the database query in order to maintain the order in which the log entries where created. If I pull out 50 records without an initial query sort then the logs returned will not be in the correct order when displayed to the user.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I agree with you and would prefer to do it this way; I just need to make sure that it works and doesn't mess with the order entries are viewed.

Comment: Look into Data Virtualization http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/498#.VDhQdPldVS0. I implemented a variation of this and it works quite well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with and seems to work pretty well, although I don't like it and think I might lean towards Lee O's suggestion in the comments above; but for the meantime since deadlines are approaching here is what I have done. `UpdateData` is on it's own thread.

```
public void UpdateData()
{
    var items = this.m_Cache.All<Model>().OrderByDescending(x => x.Timestamp).Take(50).Skip(0).ToList();

    lock (this.m_Sync)
    {
        var toRemove = this.Entries.Except(items).ToList();
        var toAdd = items.Except(this.Entries).ToList();

        foreach (Model m in toAdd)
            this.Entries.Add(m);

        foreach (Model m in toRemove)
            this.Entries.Remove(m);
    }

    this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.TotalRecords);
}
```